# Does this simulate 1D random walk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random-walk

Just started with python, so bear with me for some silly questions. Trying to figure out if the below code actually simulates a 1D random walk motion. The +/- 1 of respective random steps do not seem to add up in results.

Results:

```
positions: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3]
rr  = [0.38965102 0.88157087 0.60033975 0.84260495 0.44094328] # values to determine if positions should get +/-1
```

with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

steps = 10
positions = [2]

for i in range(steps):
    rr = np.random.random(steps)
    if rr[i] > 0.5:
        positions.append(positions[i] + 1)
    elif rr[i] < 0.5:
        positions.append(positions[i] - 1

print(positions)
print(rr)
plt.plot(positions)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `rr = np.random.random(steps)` should be before rather than inside the for loop for efficiency.  Doesn't change result, but no reason to keep calling it inside the loop to create stps samples each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is yes. It does simulate a `+ / - 1` random walk. Probably not the most effective way to do it with numpy, but it works. Here are a couple of graphs for 10,000 steps:

[image]
[image]

And, here's a different way to achieve the same thing in a more 'numpy-wise' way.

```
steps = np.random.choice([-1, 1], 1000)
positions = np.cumsum(steps)

plt.plot(positions)
plt.show()
```

Comment: That's great to hear , i am on the right track! I was not aware of some of the "numpy-wise" functions. Good to know! Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help. If this answers your question, it would be great if you could accept my answer for future generations.